# How do I append/add data to an JSON file with Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to add info to my .json file, a first name and a last name, 
from just running the script via terminal in kali linux.

I have not have had much progress I have been searching online for the past 5 hours to find a way to fix this but there has not been much progress. 
Which leaves me here to post this, anyone know how to fix this error?

- Error from Terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /root/Desktop/JSON_thingy.rb:8:in `<main>'
        3: from /root/Desktop/JSON_thingy.rb:8:in `open'
        2: from /root/Desktop/JSON_thingy.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/pure/parser.rb:118:in `parse': source in not valid JSON! (JSON::ParserError)
```

- Code

```
require 'json'
require 'json/pure'

json = {"first_name" => "john", "last_name" => "doe"}

initial_json = File.read('/root/Desktop/jsonDatabase.json')

File.open("/root/Desktop/jsonDatabase.json","w") do |f|
  f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(initial_json) << json )
end
```

- JSON

```
[
{
 "first_name": "albert",
 "last_name": "einstein"
},
{
 "first_name": "edgar",
 "last_name": "poe"
}
]
```

Comment: This code, minus the `json/pure` dependency and changing the paths, works for me. Are you sure `jsonDatabase.json` is valid JSON to start with? If not, this code won't work. You can always test it with a [JSON linting tool](https://github.com/PagerDuty/jsonlint) to be sure it's correct.

Comment: On a side note,  `JSON.pretty_generate` just adds extra spacing and new lines which may not be needed unless a human is going to be eyeballing the JSON file directly.  Also, your variable named `json` is NOT json, but a ruby hash, so you might wanna name it as such to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah just turned out to be the JSON not being a JSON file :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, simply joining two JSON strings together don't work and would result in an invalid JSON. In your example, the hash you try to add would not end up in the array but behind.

The correct way is to read the existing JSON file and parse it into a RUBY data structure and add the new hash in Ruby to the array before writing everything back to JSON.

```
require 'json'

filename = '/root/Desktop/jsonDatabase.json'

hash = { "first_name" => "john", "last_name" => "doe" }

array = JSON.parse(File.read(filename)
array << hash

File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
  f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(array))
end
```

Comment: That approach works thanks for your help. 
I did find out what the problem was. The JSON file was not a proper JSON file as the error handler suggested :/, I would not suggest coding on an empty stomach ._.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is cleaner and I would recommend using that.
However, the trace error clearly tells you what the problem is, this line:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/pure/parser.rb:118:in `parse': 
source in not valid JSON! (JSON::ParserError)
```

The part of your code which has errored is this:

```
JSON.parse(initial_json)
```

So you need to first make sure the data in the file you're loading is actually valid JSON.  You can either use the [jsonlint ruby gem](https://github.com/PagerDuty/jsonlint) or other online linters like https://jsonlint.com/ or if you're a [duck duck go user this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=online%20json%20linter&atb=v160-1&ia=answer), either of which will "beautify" your json for you.

#### UPDATE

If you use ruby jsonlint you may get a deprecation warning, you can safely ignore it.  But it's because one of its' dependencies `trollop` is throwing the deprecation warning. I have [opened a pull request](https://github.com/PagerDuty/jsonlint/pull/36) to fix it. But it looks like it might not be maintained, last commit is almost 2 years ago.  *Sigh